# How to get/set each applications window position and size in VBScript?

Tags: windows, user-interface, vbscript, window

I'd like to write a script to organize the windows I currently have open on my screen.

Ex: Move all browsers to monitor 1 and everything else to monitor 2
Ex: Make the 4 maximized windows on monitor 1 each take up equal sized quadrants on the screen
etc..

I assume VBScript would be good for this? What Objects would I use for this in a Win7 environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible in VBScript out-of-the-box, because it doesn't provide access to Windows APIs used for window management.

[AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) seems a better tool for the job. Look into the following functions and macros:

- [`WinMove`](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinMove.htm) - move windows
- [`_WinAPI_GetSystemMetrics`](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_WinAPI_GetSystemMetrics.htm)`(80)` - get the number of monitors
- `@DesktopWidth` and `@DesktopHeight` - primary monitor pixel size
- `_WinAPI_GetSystemMetrics(78)` and `_WinAPI_GetSystemMetrics(79)` - full desktop width and heigth

If the monitor dimensions are different, you can use the WMI class [`Win32_DesktopMonitor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394122.aspx) and its `ScreenWidth` and `ScreenHeigth` properties to get individual monitor dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I'd say that VBS would be good for this, I think I'd prefer C++ for this since it would involve Windows API calls which I think is easier in C++, but it depends on your skills and VBS might be fine.

The API calls I'd look at would be [EnumWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to find the windows you want to move around and then [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for moving them.

I think that if you want to move them to a secondary monitor, you should be able to do that by moving it to a position outside of the primary monitor (possibly a negative position if the secondary monitor is extended on the left for example). 
To do this you would need to be able to find out the current resolution and such which I think you can get from the WMI class [Win32_VideoController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa394512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This example shows how to get an currently exists Internet Explorer position and size on the screen, then move it to top left corner, with 800x1000 pixel size. In the example, only the first IE has moved and resized, in your case you have to handle all 4 Browser. The extended desktop usually means if you have two 1280x1024 monitor, the first monitor is in 0-1280 pixel, and the second is at 1281-1560 pixel, so the **Left** argument moves it to the desired position. For example the maximized means on both screen 1280x1024 size, and IE.Left=0 in first screen, IE.Left=1281 on the second. IE.Visible = false means hide it.

```
Set objApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

For Each objWindow In objApp.Windows
  If (InStr(objWindow.Name, "Internet Explorer")) Then
    Set IE = objWindow
        IE.Navigate "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274552/how-to-get-set-each-applications-window-position-and-size-in-vbscript"
        IE.Visible = True 
        WScript.Echo "Left: " & IE.Left & chr(10) & "Top: " & IE.Top & chr(10) & "Width: " & IE.Width & chr(10) & "Height: " & IE.Height 
        IE.Left=0
        IE.Top=0
        IE.Width=800
        IE.Height=1000
    Exit For
  End If
Next
```