# vbs start application(hh.exe) with specific window size

Tags: vbscript, size, wsh

I want to start an application (hh.exe) (Windows Help) in VBScript but I want to give that app a specific window size anb possibly a position where to open

to start the app I use this code :

```
Set hh = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell"  )
hh.Run("hh.exe -800 C:\Users\me\Desktop\HELP_I_CREATED.CHM")
```

This works but I can't find a way to give that application a size. If anybody has an idea it would be very apreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Related (or duplicate): [How to get/set each applications window position and size in VBScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14274552/113116)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the spec for this function:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(v=vs.84).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

You can see from the list of options that there is no way to specify a specific window size other than "minimized", "maximized", "original", "most recent".